# How to dynamically load the compiled Angular file into routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, module, webpack

The database stores the URL, which should load the module from the directory 'dist'.

```
{
  "personal-area": "js/compile-module.js",
  "product": "js/compile-module2.js"
}
```

Application example:

```
http://localhost:8282/#/personal-area
```

Then the application lazy (async|dynamic|any) loads the module from:

```
http://localhost:8282/js/compile-module.js
```

Modules are precompiled in advance and at the stage of building the main application they do not participate, so I do not have any paths to the sources of angular modules.

In the file with routing (app.routers.ts) I store the component handler, which pulls from the database the path to the module file on the server (based on URL).

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [

    {
        path: '**',
        component: WorkspaceOutletComponent
    },

];
```

In the main handler there is a method that tries to load the module, but for reasons I do not understand, I do not know how to make Angular connect the compiled module for the eagle and work.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class WorkspaceOutletComponent {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // detect routing and exec init
    }

    public init(workSpaceUrl: string, workSpacePathModule: string) {
        console.log(`url: ${workSpaceUrl} path: ${workSpacePathModule}`);

        this.router.resetConfig([
            {
                path: workSpaceUrl, loadChildren: workSpacePathModule
            }
        ]);

        this.router.navigate([workSpaceUrl])
            .then(() => console.log('Navigate to'))
            .catch((e) => console.error('Error', e));
    }

}
```

The application is built using webpack 2. But at the moment when I replace routing, he writes me a mistake, and I do not even know where to dig to dynamically load the module (which I need to come from the database), I do not know the reference to the module during the assembly, nothing, I do not even have source codes, So I need third-party modules to load into runtime. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

If I use SystemJS. It also does not help, it tries to load the module from the disk (from source).

```
this.router.resetConfig([
            {
                path: workSpaceUrl, loadChildren: SystemJS.import(workSpacePathModule).then(function (m) {
                    console.log(m);
                })
            }
        ]);
```

[image]

Here a little is told about how the loading of modules works:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4234#issuecomment-275345763

Do I understand correctly that Angular needs an exact name so that he compiles a hash map. And that's why you can not pass it as I do it, but what should I do if I do not know the correspondence between the path on the disk (since I do not have source codes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether the reset route way will work or not, but I know that you'll need to generate lazy routes for all modules you might use.

The value for `loadChildren` will have to be a static `string`. You cannot even call a function in there to get that `string`. Even that confuses the Angular CLI magic that works with Webpack to generate the lazy routes.

It should be fine to generate all like lazy routes anyway, and then in runtime load the one(s) you are interested in. Just be careful that `resetConfig` could be resetting the whole config.

There's also `linkNgModuleFactory` which can get you an instance of a module factory (what Angular creates from a module after comiling either in browser or AoT), which you might be able to use it with `NgComponentOutlet`.

Comment: What does it mean in your case "need to generate lazy routes for all modules you might use"?

Comment: Are there any examples where you can achieve a dynamic string, rather than a static string in loadChildren?

Comment: How can I download the routes and modules of interest if the data comes from the database?

Comment: What I meant is that you write all the routes as lazy routes (`loadChildren` and a `path`). You do not just rely on what the DB tells, you list all of them, so they get separate bundles and can be lazy loaded.

Comment: Excuse me, I do not quite understand. In the usual case, when I have no application connected to the database; I work like this: loadChildren: "app/path-to-typescript-module.ts?chunkNate=name-module". Now I do not have paths to typescript files. Then what should I do according to your methodology? Can attach a sample code or plunker?